# Is 'so I did', and other like expressions, at the end of a sentence good English?

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis, hiberno-english

In Northern Ireland people will say 'He went to Bohemia on holiday, so he did', or 'I need to do some shopping, so I do'. Is this correct English?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, of course it is, but it's not normally found outside Ireland.

Comment: @ Barrie England. Does that mean that any English dialect forms can be regarded as correct English? I could try a few Norfolk ones on you if you like!  There used to be something called a Northern British Standard. My grandson, who is a Mancunian for example, will say 'It is very warm inside, is our house.' The Standard Queen's English would be 'Our house is very warm inside'.   Do we recognise dialect forms as having equal parity. Now, do be careful, or I'll give you a few of those Norfolk ones!

Comment: WS2: rhetorical questions are rhetorical, and nonsensical questions are nonsensical. Do you have a point?

Comment: @RegDwight. And insults are insults. What's your problem?

Comment: WS2 Define "correct English".

Comment: @TrevorD. The English which would be accepted by a GCSE or A Level examiner as correct. Or for what is acceptable from someone taking one of the examinations which foreign students take. If there is no such thing as 'correct' English I am sure you will accept my using, in the Norfolk idiom 'Do he do as he do do do you let me know'. (yes it contains 'do' five times. That is a perfectly grammatical sentence in Norfolk. Try punctuating it and tell me what it means.

Comment: WS2 Please do not answer every comment as if I'm disagreeing with you. I'm not! But you asked "Is this correct English?"; Barry answered "Yes"; and you disagreed. It's therefore not inappropriate to ask whether you are both using the term in the same way - and it seems that you are not.  Perhaps the term 'standard English' would be better? OTOH, if your definition relies on British exams, I don't know whether the use of Americanisms & N.Am spellings would be accepted in UK GCSE & A-levels as 'correct' or 'standard' English.

Comment: @WS2 The answers given will vary, depending on whether or not the repsondent is a [prescriptivist.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_prescription)  A prescriptivist will almost certainly assert that dialect forms do **not** have parity.   From the perspective of this native American English speaker, your question is neither nonsensical, nor rhetorical.  Thanks for your contributions to ELU.

Comment: @Trevor. I did not 'disagree' with Barrie, as you suggest. I was simply attempting to explore this relationship between the Queen's English and dialect. I assume since neither you nor anyone else has attempted to parse and explain my Norfolk sentence, that you all agree that what is acceptable as standard has to be defined in some way or other.

Comment: I hesitated over using "disagree": maybe "questioned Barry's answer" would be better. Yes, "correct" or "standard" must, as a minimum, have some kind of mutually understood meaning. Sometimes what is considered 'correct' in AmE may be considered 'incorrect' in BrE & *vice versa*. Also, what is considered acceptable in speech may not be so acceptable in writing.

Comment: The term Queen’s English is unhelpful. Here’s my definition of Standard English from my blog http://caxton1485.wordpress.com/: ‘Standard English is the variety of the language generally used in published writing, and typically in areas of life such as education, courts of law, public service broadcasting and government. For this reason it is most important that children are taught this variety in school. It is not, however, the variety of the language spoken by most people. As the linguist Peter Trudgill has said “Standard English is . . . not the English language”.’

Comment: @Barrie England. I know of Peter Trudgill very well, and have corresponded with him as he is the world's leading authority on the Norfolk dialect. He was kind enough to review for me what I had written as the Wikipedia entry on the subject. His book however accords a far more extensive treatment. We are both Norfolk born contemporaries. And I quite agree with what you quote him as saying. I think he holds that only 3% of speakers in Britain use the Received Pronunciation.

Comment: Then I take it you know his paper here: http://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/home/dick/SEtrudgill.htm

Comment: @Barrie England. No I hadn't read that one but I shall look forward to doing so. The English with which I concern myself here is the English I use in historical essays. 'The old boy was bloody knackered after his long trip' may be 'Standard English' to PT, but I would not dream of using anything like that in an essay!

Comment: That is exactly his point.

Answer (score 4):

These parentheticals, tacked on to the ends of sentences, have the same pragmatic role as the pragmatic markers (veridical / emphasising / focusing) *truly* or *in truth* or *the facts of the matter are* (which are, however, usually put before the matrix sentence).

As to their grammaticality, it's almost certain that a panel of professors of linguistics would pronounce them '**not ungrammatical**'.

As to the advisability of using them, the effect they would produce outside Ireland would be to convince a listener that the speaker was either from Ireland, or affecting an Irish style of speaking. If the latter, this **might** *be considered **highly inappropriate***.

**"Correct"?**

Answer (score 2):

As an Englishman from the Midlands of England, I certainly regard this as perfectly good English. I find the addition of 'so he did'; 'so I can' etc. at the end of a sentence to be fascinating - not least because of the fluency with which it is done. It must be quite difficult, because one has to instantly recap what one has just said in order to get the right verb/tense etc.
Try it yourself  - it's not as easy as those from Northern Ireland make it sound.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: @Chenmunka  It's less of a comment than Barrie's answer and that has five upvotes.

Answer (score -5):

This question led to some bitter-sweet comments, one was to the point : "**Define correct English**".

If English has no system of reference, it will progressively evolve like French, Italian, Spanish, Romanian and others : only partially understandable between each other, at least in writing, fairly easy to learn one of them if you already know another one, but no more.

I believe that the only one referential you may rely on is what is called "Oxford English", "BBC English", "Queen's / King's English". And when you speak it, you are understood all over the world, not the reverse.

You can see the damages on "Stack Exchange" itself :

- I was down-voted a number of times for what I wrote, correct I believe in London, but not in the States, for instance the use of present perfect and preterit ;
- whereas I never reacted, I was horrified by some American-English turns of phrasing which would never been accepted by an English teacher, or an European teacher of English. For instance, I read, from one American member with a very high reputation "never use whom" ; in the UK, mixing up "who" and "whom" would be a sign of deep illiteracy.

To answer the question, I would say "it is not correct English, but perhaps correct Irish, which is a dialect".

However, it is difficult to tell an American that he speaks just a dialect, and moreover an impoverished one (by far less vocabulary as compared with the man-in-the-street in the UK ; they compensate for that by using strong words).

Comment: This is commentary, rather than an answer to the question.

Comment: @MarkThorin As a native American English speaker, I find your last paragraph mildly offensive.  I have no trouble with the assertion that American English is a dialect, but I have a hard time accepting your judgments as anything more than nationalist arrogance.

Comment: I regret (as a Brit) to have to say I agree with @Lumberjack. I also have to disagree with you in stating that "when you speak [British English], you are understood all over the world." One place where you are often *not* understood is in the USA - and also to some extent in Canada (as I know because I've just spent 2 weeks in Canada & my brother & family live there).

Comment: @Lumberjack. I have heard it said, by an intelligent and sympathetic British observer, living in Washington DC, that the average educated American speaks more grammatically correct English than his or her equivalent in Britain, (perhaps because grammar is more formally taught in American schools) BUT with an infinitely smaller vocabulary. My own impression from working with Americans for years is that they are very strong on metaphor. They seem to have an infinite number of similes etc to call upon, but the vocabulary, I have to agree, is their weak point.

Comment: You are confusing the level of education of the average "man on the street" and the vocabulary available in a dialect. Whether the average person has a large vocabulary or not does not depend on the dialect but on whether that person has read enough books to develop a rich vocabulary. Also, your point about _whom_ is just plain wrong. If anything, the Americans tend to use it more than the Brits. See, for example, [this](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv47.shtml) BBC article that suggests it is not used in conversation in the UK.

Comment: I am sorry if the last sentence has not been understood as self-derisory (but not derisive) : UK against USA ! I heard from David and Goliath, but all the same ... What I regret is : a) a reduced vocabulary b) a grammatical impoverishment (I mentioned the confusion between "who" and "whom") c) the inability to have a new standard, however necessary it should be. Despite my provocative tone, don't believe I feel nationalist : I am both British and French, then sometimes schizophrenic, but not at all hostile to American culture ! Lumberjack, please don't practise (not US practice) against me.

Comment: Few speakers of British English, including this one, use _whom_ other than in the most formal contexts.

Comment: But that is where you're wrong, there is no evidence whatsoever for a) since it does not depend on dialect. There are no poor or rich dialects, the vocabulary can be shared across all of them. There is even less evidence for b), indeed you could make a better case for a grammatical impoverishment in BrEn than AmEn. I already mentioned that the who/whom distinction is more respected in American dialects and the continued use of the conditional _were_. Both of these are in decline in the UK. This kind of broad statement with absolutely no sources cited is not good form. Especially if wrong.

Comment: @Barrie England. Well, I just checked some of my work. I used it once in an essay of 700 words and 4 times in one of 3,500 words. So  in written work I appear to use it once every 800 words. I perhaps use it less in everyday speech, but I certainly do use it.

Comment: The British National Corpus has 197,855 records for ‘who’, against 12,444 for ‘whom’.

Comment: I have not noticed many academics from the humanities on the site. Their contributions would be interesting. In Universities all emphasis is on ensuring students use a high standard of written English. Elegant form is encouraged. Whatever you may think of Prof David Starkey (and to me he is bumptious and arrogant), his 'Six Wives' is a delight to read. He uses the kind of English my grammar-school teachers held up as an ideal. How can you possibly write elegant readable English without using an extensive vocabulary, words like whom, the conditional tense, occasional subjunctives etc.