# What do you call it when someone repeats part of a sentence?

Tags: grammar

What do you call it when somebody repeats part of a sentence?

For example:

'I like walking I do'

Comment: This has been discussed before, especially with reference to the Irish *I like walking, so I do*.

Comment: @WS2: I think this is the question you're talking about: [Is 'so I did', and other like expressions, at the end of a sentence good English?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/131319/is-so-i-did-and-other-like-expressions-at-the-end-of-a-sentence-good-english)