# Repeated verb in a sentence?

Tags: word-usage

I've seen some usages like this:

> You've got there some really nice thing, you've got there.
>
> He is a big jerk, he is.

Or something like that. I don't have an actual example right now, sadly, but I remember there was a verb at the beginning of the sentence and the same verb was repeated at the end.

Have you ever come across something like that? Can you point me to some sources where I can learn more about that?

Edit: I believe my question is different from the one suggested as I'm talking about usages where the verb itself is repeated, not the "do/would" in their place.

Edit2: So I guess my question is twofold:
1. Is that correct English/does anyone use it like that? (You've already answered that one.)
2. Any materials sources about this usage so I can learn **when** and **how** to use it correctly?

Comment: Your first example doesn't sound remotely idiomatic to me. The second looks similar to the relatively common informal usage in, for example, [*I'm going, me*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22I%27m+going%2C+me.+You+catch+me.%22), where repetion of the subject arguably emphasizes the subject: *That's what **I** am going to do, regardless of what anyone else does*.

Comment: Great question, +1)

Comment: For your first I think you need this sentence: "You've got some really nice things there, you have".

Comment: You might hear the first one as "You've got there some really nice thing, you have", but not as you've written it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is 'so I did', and other like expressions, at the end of a sentence good English?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/131319/is-so-i-did-and-other-like-expressions-at-the-end-of-a-sentence-good-english)

Comment: @Araucaria Great minds think alike. :-)

Comment: @WS2 It's related to 'so I did' but is not a duplicate. Plenty of people use this form for emphasis but without using 'so', which seems to be a  N. Irish thing.

Comment: @WS2 Similar possibly to that excellent question, but not a dupe, I don't think. Reason being that we expect to be able to make Adjuncts out of adverb phrases, but not from finite declarative clauses. :)

Comment: @Araucaria: So riddle me this: What difference if any does it make if we transpose to *That's a really good question, is that!* (which sounds far more idiomatic to me, at least).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't know, except I reckon *that is* is more common down south and *is that* is more common up North where people speak better than they do down here ;)

Comment: @Araucaria: Good point. Now that you mention it, I *do* think the "inverted" form sounds more "Northern". But that might just be because it sounds a bit more "dialectal" (read, "colloquial, uneducated"). I tend to classify all "non-Estuary English" dialects as Northern unless I'm forced to acknowledge it as specifically, say, West Country dialect.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Really? I think the *that is* sounds a little child-like, but I don't get that from the inverted one. It just sounds more characterful to me. (shrugs)

Comment: @Araucaria: Oh, I agree *that is* would often be somewhat "child-like". But to me, *is that* has connotations of being a bit "antiquated" (usages that were once "normal" often survive only as dialect). It reminds me of *Old King Cole was a merry old soul, and a merry old soul **was he***. That's to say, somewhat medieval syntax.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, that's it! Couldn't put my finger on it.

Comment: @Araucaria:  I also completely agree your "more characterful" assessment. I reckon we've *both* learned something from this not-entirely-off-topic exchange (so please accept my thanks for what ***I*** have gotten out of it! :)

Comment: @Araucaria If one can say it like that "That's a really good question that is!" then that's exactly what I meant in my question.

Comment: @NPS Yes, you can say it like that! I guessed that was the kind of thing you were after :)

Answer (score 2):

I’m pretty sure I’ve heard thinks like that. Generally it sounds as though you repeat the verb for emphasis, as if to say, you can rest assured that’s the truth.

I’ve come across these passages in Kipling’s *Plain Tales from the Hills*. Kipling is reporting the characters’ speech, and in this case I think the repetition is Kipling’s own sarcastic voice.  The following is from [*The Other Man*](http://pinkmonkey.com/dl/library1/kplng049.pdf). Schreiderling is an obnoxious man:

> [Schreiderling] always prided himself on speaking his mind, did Shreiderling.
>
> He always set great store on speaking his mind, did Shreiderling.

This one is from [*A Friend’s Friend*](http://pinkmonkey.com/dl/library1/kplng002.pdf). Jevon is Kipling’s guest at a ball, and he is hopelessly drunk:

> But Jevon wasn’t going; not he. He knew what was good for him, he did; and he wasn’t going to be dictated to by any loconial nigger-driver, he wasn’t; and I was the friend who had formed his infant mind and brought him up to buy Benares brassware and fear God, so I was; and we would have many more blazing good drunks together, so we would;