# What do you make of sentences such as: "He completely missed his shot, did Mark!"

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I sometimes hear people, Brits in my experience, say things like :

- He completely missed his shot, did Mark!
- He's out of his mind, is Ronnie!

The sense is clear but I haven't seen this described anywhere.  Is that something that is more of a British way of saying things?  Is it colloquial or can it be found in more formal types of speeches?

Comment: There are commas missing in both examples.

Comment: I see what you mean, I didn't include commas, because the way it's pronounced is a continuous flow without any pause but there might be a slight rise in intonation after "shot" or "mind".

Comment: On the contrary, the intonation drops right down for "did" (resp. "is"). Then it rises from low to mid-level during "Mark" (resp. "Ronnie"). And yes, I would use commas too. (A good question though!)

Comment: Commas in written English do not always turn into pauses when the same words are spoken. Consider "Hi, Petritien, did the comment by @HotLicks answer your question?". If that was spoken (without the @ of course) you would be very unlikely to hear pauses after Hi or your name.

Comment: Thanks for the answers!  I'll trust you on intonation, which, as a non-native speaker, I've always found a bit baffling.  I'm adding the commas to show that there are two clauses in the sentence.

Comment: Very closely related: [Is 'so I did', and other like expressions, at the end of a sentence good English?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/131319/is-so-i-did-and-other-like-expressions-at-the-end-of-a-sentence-good-english)
)

Comment: Thanks for the reference, Edwin.  I gather from the exchange in the other query that the construction I'm asking about might be typical of northern England.  I definitely remember it being used by John Virgo, the snooker commentator, but also, I think, by Dennis Taylor, so it could be typical of Irish English as well.